# Discrete Math Subsets of a Set

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

A pizza parlor has six meat toppings and four vegetable toppings that can be added to a pizza. Pizzas also come in three different sizes. How many pizzas can be ordered that have at least one meat topping and at least one vegetable topping?  You use subsets of a set and get [2^(6 meat toppings)] [2^(4 vegetable toppings)] [3 different sizes] = 3072 pizzas.  Is this correct? And why is it that we use 2^number of sets? What is the significance of 2 when doing these problems?

Comment: The number two is often there because for each topping there are two possibilities - the topping is on the pizza or it isn't. But your answer is not entirely correct, because you have counted even pizzas with no topping at all!

Answer (score 3):

For each topping, we have two choices: (1) put the topping on the pizza, or (2) don't put the topping on the pizza. There are 10 such toppings, so there are $2^{10}$ different ways to top a given pizza. Since there are $3$ sizes, then there are $3\cdot 2^{10}=3072$ different possible pizzas. However, you must now *exclude* the pizzas that have no vegetable toppings or no meat toppings.

There are $3\cdot 2^6$ pizzas that have no vegetable toppings, and $3\cdot 2^4$ pizzas with no meat toppings. There are $3$ pizzas with no toppings at all--those three fall into the no vegetables category and the no meat category, and so we counted those twice. Hence, there are $3\cdot 2^6+3\cdot 2^4-3=237$ pizzas that have no vegetable toppings or no meat toppings, and so there are $3072-237=2835$ pizzas of the sort that you want.